# iOS: Get String from NSDictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have an NSDictionary object.

How do i get json String from this object?

```
var myNSDictObject ...
...
println(myNSDictObject.description)
```

This prints a pretty formatted string, with semicolons, newlines inserted etc.. it is not even proper json. So this does not work.

Comment: The NSDictionary was created from JSON, and you want  to get a JSON string again?

Comment: I think that you're trying to get object for the description key, when you `println( myNSDictObject.description)` this prints the object's description, you may want to try `println(myNSDictObject.objectForKey("description")`

Comment: Martin R> Trying to extract a part of the original JSON, not the same JSON back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func generateJSONString(dictionary : NSDictionary) -> NSString? {
    var error : NSError?

    if let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: nil, error: &error) {
        return NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } else {
        println("\(error?.localizedDescription)")
        return nil
    }
}
```